# How to get the total number of rows in DataTables using Jquery in JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatables

I am using a datatable in my application. When loading the page i need to display the number of rows of the table in a span. I am using  table.data().count() to get the count of the rows. But its not giving correct value.

JSP:

```
<table id="example" class="" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="padding: 10px">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <!-- <th>S No</th> -->
        <th>Doc Id</th>
        <th id="Position">Geo</th>
        <th id="Position">Practice</th>
        <th id="Position">Opportunity Id</th>
        <th id="Position">Reference Id</th>
        <th id="Position">Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
$(document).ready(function() {
                            var rowCount = table.data().count();
                            alert(rowCount);
                            });
```

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you cannot rely on `ready()` being executed after the table is initialised. It is rare the `ready()` construct is actually needed or even useful, and when people think they need it, it is often the side effect of bad design. I have literally seen hundreds of posts here on SO where people have problems caused by peculiar nested `ready()` scopes, and most of the times the only reason for the use of `ready()` is "tradition" or "just to be sure", i.e [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Secondly there is no `count()` method on `data()`. There is, but this is because `data()` in fact is returning an API, the data as an array with API methods attached.

So use `Array.length` to get the number of rows, and place the code inside dataTables `initComplete` callback :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   initComplete: function() {
      $('#count').text( this.api().data().length )
   }
})
```

the markup could look like this :

```html
<p id="count"></p>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/f9zq9gn8/**

Comment: thank u for your answer. Now the problem has been solved. But now i need to know how to pass the value of the row to an jsp tag?? I set the value of the count to a variable. i don't know how to pass that to a <p> tag. Please help

Comment: @Shanmugapriya, it all run client side, after the page is loaded,  so you just need javascript (jQuery for convenience). I dont know how your tag looks like, but have updated with an example. Add an `id` to the tag you want to place the row count, that should be all. It does not have to be a `<p>` tag, it could be `<span>`, `<em>` or similar.

Comment: This not right answer. If paging is true, the result are always the `pageLength` result if more items as `pageLength`exist.  If i have 200 items, and `pageLength = 100`, then your length are 100, *not* 200.

Answer (score 0):

To build on davidkonrad's answer, but keeping the function to datatables:

```
    let table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            //Do your ajax stuff to get your data
        },
        initComplete: function () {
            //After the ajax has run, initComplete can get the total count of lines .
            console.log(table.data().count())
        }
    });
```

This was the only thing that worked for me.

Keep in mind that this only works on the content within the currently loaded table. If you use pagination, you're going to need to make an additional call to your backend.

Comment: Thats not the right answer. If paging is true, the result are always the pageLength result if more items as pageLengthexist. If i have 200 items, and pageLength = 100, then your length are 100, not 200.

Comment: @TheAlphaGhost yes technically true. However OP wasnt asking for that. And in that case you would need to make an additional call to the backend. Ive amended my post to indicate its only for data in the current table and wont be helpful for pagination tables.